# Zend SubForm: How to disable changing of element names inside subforms?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a zend form in which I need each element to be wrapped by a display group. Then I need a group of elements to be wrapped in another display group. Since zend form does not support nested display groups I use subform instead.

So, my structure now is:

```
Form
--- SubForm (1)
--- --- DisplayGroup (1-1)
--- --- --- Element (1)
--- --- DisplayGroup (1-2)
--- --- --- Element (2)
--- SubForm (2)
--- --- DisplayGroup (2-1)
--- --- --- Element (3)
--- --- DisplayGroup (2-2)
--- --- --- Element (4)
```

etc.

From this, however, comes the problem that each subform is set as a parent to each element that belongs to it. This changes the name of the element, f.e. `name="username"` becomes `name="subformname[username]"`.

Since I am using the subform as a substitute of the display group, I don't need it's extra functionality.

How can I disable this changing of the names?

P.S.: I am using a custom function to "bulk process" each element (trivial stuff - remove decorators, set labels etc.), so I was able to force `setAttrib('name', $element -> getName())`, but it turns out that this only works for regular form elements. It does not work on ZendX form elements like datepickers, colorpickers etc.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap each element with a display group?

Comment: Each element should inherit span4 or span6 from the twitter bootstrap css framework in order to appear in columns. Further more it should be in the Zend_Form not in the view - client requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments you said you're only using display groups to give the element a twitter bootstrap grid class. You don't need to use display groups for this, just add an additional HtmlTag decorator to each form element, or add a class to one of the existing ones. Then you can use display groups for their intended purpose, giving you:

```
Form
--- DisplayGroup (1)
--- --- Element (1)
--- --- Element (2)
--- DisplayGroup (2)
--- --- Element (3)
--- --- Element (4)
```

if you have any trouble, edit your question to include the your 'bulk process' code that is modifying the existing decorators we can suggest how it could be modified.

Edit: Getting a decorator to wrap the label and the form element is just down to the order in which your decorators are specified. Here's an example:

```
$element->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
        ->addDecorator('Errors')
        ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description'))
        ->addDecorator('Label', array('optionalSuffix' => ':', 'requiredSuffix' => ':*'))
        ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'span4'));
```

The viewHelper decorator renders the form element itself. Each subsequent decorator is wrapped 'around' the existing content. Exactly how that is rendered depends a bit on the decorator itself, but in the example above you'll see a div tag with the class 'span4' as the last decorator, which means the div will wrap everything else.

Comment: I have tried using an HtmlTag decorator, but it is applied to the input element only, and the label is left outside of the wrapper. I need a decorator that would wrap both the label and the element. If you think I am wrong about how HtmlTag works, would you please place a working example?

Comment: That's just down to the order of the decorators. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I did not know the order mattered.. should have paid more attention. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The array notation used in sub form element names is controlled by `Zend_Form::$_isArray`.  It's *false* in `Zend_Form` and *true* in `Zend_Form_SubForm`, which extends `Zend_Form`.

You can either call `setIsArray(FALSE)` on your sub form or override `Zend_Form::$_isArray` in your sub form if it extends `Zend_Form_SubForm`.